# Web stress testing, the pg encountered an exception, TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, stress-testing, python-3.11

env：
Django 4.1.3
drf 3.14.0
psycopg2 2.9.5
postgres 14.7
gunicorn 21.2.0
eventlet 0.33.3

I conducted basic stress testing on the django framework,  and my View is as follows

```
class HealthCheckView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            Role.objects.filter().count()
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=499)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I use the following command to start the web service:

gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application -c myapp/settings/gunicorn.conf.py

gunicorn.conf.py content is as follows:

```
bind = f'0.0.0.0:{GUNICORN_PORT}'
worker_class = 'eventlet'
workers = 6
```

Then I used the **ab** tool for stress testing:

ab -n 10000 -c 500 https://10.30.7.7/api/v1/healthz/

**When the concurrency is 500, the result is good.**

**When I continued to increase the number of concurrent requests, some of them were unable to connect to the database.**

> ```
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
>         Is the server running on host "10.30.7.7" and accepting
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

The database configuration file is as follows:

```
max_connections = 4096
shared_buffers = 16GB
effective_cache_size = 48GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 1MB
huge_pages = try
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 20
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 20
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4
```

How should I conduct the investigation?

Reducing the number of concurrent requests can avoid problems, but 500 concurrent requests are obviously not many.
At the same time, I have also tried deploying databases using Docker and compiling and installing databases using source code. This problem occurs when the concurrency is high.

Comment: You can't actually handle 4096 concurrent DB connections on your hardware can you? Start by setting a reasonable value and checking your connection pooling setup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, my application will not occupy 4096 database connections. I have adjusted the database connection and the above issue occurs between 500 and 4096.

Comment: So I think the maximum number of database connections should be unrelated to this issue. In addition, my web program does not use a database connection pool, and Django's default processing is to create a connection for each request, and release the connection after the request is completed.

Comment: "500 concurrent requests are obviously not many"  That is hardly obvious and in fact is just wrong.

Comment: "Django's default processing is to create a connection for each request, and release the connection after the request is completed"  Change from the default to something more suitable for your use case.  That is the point of testing, is it not?

Comment: Yes, after I enabled the database persistence connection for django, there were no more errors reported. It seems that it was caused by frequent creation and destruction of connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I have temporarily solved this problem.

I changed the validity time of Django's database connection.

Add **CONN_MAX_AGE** for Django.

**It seems that it was caused by frequent creation and destruction of connections.**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': POSTGRES_DB,
    'USER': POSTGRES_USER,
    'PASSWORD': POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    'HOST': POSTGRES_HOST,
    'PORT': POSTGRES_PORT,
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600}
}
```

**1.gunicorn + eventlet (10 workers)**

A large number of connections to be created and deleted.

The quantity fluctuates between a few hundred to a few thousand.

This method still leads to the occurrence of the above error.

**2.gunicorn + gthread (20 workers, 40 threads)**

A limited number of database connections have been created.

max_connections = workers * threads = 800

This method works well.